# How to set a state that is on a component?

Tags: reactjs

On reactjs, how can I setNotify again a state that is on a component?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const NotificationError = (props) => {

    const [notify, setNotify] = useState(false);

    // if (props.message === "") {
    //     props.message = "Some Error"
    // }

    // if (props.message !== "") {
    //     setNotify(false)
    // }

    // if (props) {
    //     const [notify] = useState(true)
    // }

    console.log("notify.state:", props)

    const closeNotification = (e) => {
        console.log("Should be closing notification")
        setNotify(e)
    }

    return (
        <div className="notification is-danger" style={notify ? {display: 'none'} : {display: 'block'}}>
            <button className="delete" onClick={() => closeNotification(true)}></button>
            Error: {props.message}
        </div>
    )
}

export default NotificationError
```

If I use the following:

```
if (props) {
    const [notify] = useState(true)
}
```

I get the error,

> Line 17:26:  React Hook "useState" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

If I use the following

```
if (props.message !== "") {
        setNotify(true)
    }
```

It throws the following...

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to
> prevent an infinite loop.

Simply, I am not understanding this. Can you please help? :(

Comment: You cannot use useState conditionally. For the condition things, you should useEffect and you can set your value when condition changed.

Comment: I tried, useEffect(() => {
        // const notify = useState(true)
        return () => {
          // Clean up the subscription
          notify.closeNotification(false);
        };
      }, notify); but the notification is still not showing up.

Comment: you cannot define useState in the useEfffect define useState out of the useEffect and setState in the useEffect conditonally.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite you logic to something like:

```
const NotificationError = (props) => {
  const [notify, setNotify] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.message === "") {
      props.setMessage('Some Error');
    }
    setNotify(false);
  }, [props.message]);

  return (
    <div
      className="notification is-danger"
      style={notify ? { display: "none" } : { display: "block" }}
    >
      <button className="delete" onClick={() => setNotify(true)}></button>
      Error: {props.message}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Props are immutable so if you want to change a message you should pass a callback.
Also, take a read about [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `useEffect` hook for such cases. It works similar to `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` in class component. It means the function that you pass as the first argument of `useEffect` hook triggers the first time when your component mounts and then every time any of the elements of the array changes that you pass as the second argument.

Here is the code example:

```
const NotificationError = (props) => {
    const [notify, setNotify] = useState(false);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(props.message != '') {
           setNotify(false);
        }
    }, [props.message])

    const closeNotification = (e) => {
        console.log("Should be closing notification")
        setNotify(e)
    }

    return (
        <div className="notification is-danger" style={notify ? {display: 'none'} : {display: 'block'}}>
            <button className="delete" onClick={() => closeNotification(true)}></button>
            Error: {props.message}
        </div>
    )
}
```